# How to calculate maximum length of VARCHAR type in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, varchar, page-size

According to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_stringdatatypes.htm):

> VARCHAR(n)    Varying-length character strings with a maximum length of
>   n bytes. n must be greater than 0 and less than a **number that depends
>   on the page size of the table space**. The maximum length is 32704.

If I correctly understand this definition, maximum length can be anything less then 32704, according to the configuration of database.

I wonder, how to calculate the *current* maximum length of VARCHAR type for a *specific* DB2-database using SQL commands?

Please note: the solution must include automatic determination of page size; this value can not be a parameter of suggested code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the page size of your tablespace from [`sysibm.systablespace`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtable.htm):

```
select pgsize from sysibm.systablespace where name='FOO'
```

The [create table documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtable.htm) gives information on how the maximum `varchar` size relates to the page file size (search for maximum record size).  I don't want to give a definitive answer, because it is rather complex and I don't have DB2 on z/OS to test it.  But you should be able to determine the maximum lengths for each page size from a combination of that information and trial-and-error.

**Note:** this answer is for DB2 on z/OS (assumed because that was the source of the documentation quote above).  It is slightly different on LUW, but can be found if you go to the equivalent documentation pages.

Comment: Could you please check: there isn't table called "systablespace" with column named "name" in my sysibm scheme. There is "systablespaceS" and it contains column named "TBSPACE". In any case I accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Andremoniy, in that case it sounds like you are using DB2 for LUW.  I assumed you were using z/OS because of the documentation you linked to (the DB2 docs can be confusing.  I suggest always including your version number and platform when searching, so you get the correct version).